# Waiting for firebase to give back data xcode

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, asynchronous

I highly doubt there hasn't been given answer to this question but I can't figure it out with outer posts on stackoverflow.

I am pulling out data with the observeSingleEvent method in xcode swift.

The problem is that firebase is async and the code runs through even though I wanted to wait for firebase to return the data.

```
var requests_list:NSMutableDictionary = [:]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let userID: String = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!
    ref.child("users").child(userID).child("requests").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
        let requests = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
        for (key,_) in requests{
            ref.child("users").child(key as! String).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
                let value1 = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
                let username = value1["username"]!
                let keyvalue = key as! String
                self.requests_list[keyvalue] = username
                print(self.requests_list)
            })
        }
    })
}
```

This is my tableView to calculate how many rows there must be.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.requests_list.allValues[indexPath.row] as? String
    print(self.requests_list.allValues[0] as! String)
    return cell
}
```

And this is where the cell are being filled. problem is the program thinks the list is empty so they don't fill in the rows.

Comment: @Sammy right on point! This code is not a good idea. OP- I think maybe you're missing a piece of the puzzle. In general, you're going to want your UI elements to be fast and responsive. To do that, you want to minimize the amount of extraneous code they have to deal with. In the case of a tableView (and other controls) they are backed by a dataSource. So the idea would be to populate your dataSource (typically an array) with data from Firebase prior to showing the tableView and the tableView would pull its data from that dataSource.

Comment: There's really no noticeable delay when dealing with Firebase - it's blisteringly fast. I did a test a while back and loaded 1,000 nodes of data, where each node contained user info; name, address, city, state etc and the load times averaged .8 seconds, so doing that on app start has no noticeable impact. That being said, there's usually no reason to load that much data so use pagination to load the data to present to the user - it's totally seamless. Firebase also offers offline persistence so if the connection is interrupted, the app continues to function.